# What is the Size of an Arraylist containing null object along with other Object in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which contains some Objects as well as some `null` elements.

It seems the `null` is not occupying any space and the array size returned is only that occupied by the object, and doesn't take into account the 'null' elements.

```
//Inside for loop 
private void addPhone(ArrayList<PhoneBean > phoneBeanList,Member member) {
    if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(member.getStatus())) {
        PhoneBean phoneBean = new PhoneBean ();
        phoneBean .setPhNum("12345");
        phoneBeanList.add(phoneBean);   
    }else {
        phoneBeanList.add(null);

    } 
}
```

When `addPhone()` runs twice I am expecting the `phoneBeanList` size to return 2 but instead its 1.
Is it because `null` does not contribute to the `ArrayList` size?

Any idea what do I need to change/add into the list if the status is anything other than `A` ?

Comment: run the code and do phoneBeanList.size() afterwards - it will tell you. Even better - write a unit test.

Comment: @Matthias Huttar I did that already and the phoneBeanList.size()  is returning 1 even when it contains one phoneBean object and 1 null object

Comment: @Bidisha are you sure about that?  The way your method is written it will add _either_ `phoneBean` or null, not both.

Comment: Are you doing any other action before call `addPhone()` second time? Would share that part of your code?

Comment: @rodnuk Yes...actually I am using an api to get rows of member from database and it can contain multiple Phone rows of HomePh type or Workph type...so for each phone type this method is getting called and the phoneBeanList is populated

Comment: `null` does contribute to list size.  Are you sure it's running twice? Is it getting the same list instance? is the list being cleared in between calls? Try adding some debug statements to print the content/size of the list at the beginning and end of your method - that will likely reveal the issue

Comment: @Chris : the same list is getting passed..because when I add 2 rows of Phone with status "A" I get List size as 2

Comment: @Bidisha Take a look at my solution below.

Comment: @Bidisha - It sounds like nobody is able to reproduce this problem based on your posted code. Can you update to include a [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example)](http://sscce.org/) that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please include the code that calls this function.  Without the code that calls the function we can't tell what you're doing with the variable outside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because "null" does not contributes to the ArrayList Size?

I would say no. It is not because you added `null`.

According to the implementation of `.add()` method in ArrayList, there is no explicit condition to handle `null` objects. Hence even adding a `null` into the list, it should increase the array size.

Infact, the only thing they would do is to check whether there is a need to grow the current array which is backing your array list. Your `null` object will be added to the list after that.

You can take a look at their implementation for `.add()` in ArrayList:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1); 
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

---

> When addPhone() runs 2 times one for member Status "A" and other as "D" I was expecting the phoneBeanList size to return 2 but instead its 1

From your method signature of `addPhone()`:

```
private void addPhone(ArrayList<PhoneBean > phoneBeanList,Member member
```

The user is to choose an ArrayList instance to be added. I **highly suspect** you added an element to **another ArrayList instance**, which explains why it is showing the list size as 1.

If that is not the case, there could be other reasons which is not being shown in your codes.

- Did you remove any elements from the list before printing?
- Is there any other methods affecting the ArrayList you were printing?

Comment: @Bidisha Take a look at my solution.

Comment: Thanks to everybody...My API is not getting the rows other than "A".Consider this Question solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can add null to an ArrayList. So to answer your question, the size of a list with null and another object is 2.

```
/* package whatever; */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(null);
        items.add("test");
        System.out.println("Items size: " + items.size());
        // Prints 2
    }
}
```

Try it https://ideone.com/WeEtqh

Comment: Yes thats what I was thinking...but not happening with my code one time if condition ran and populated next time else ran populated null ..when I tried to get the size() from outside the loop its 1 and not 2